# Marketpress to Magento: 301 redirect using htaccess

Tags: magento-1.9, wordpress, 301-redirect

We're moving a site from MarketPress (WP plugin) to Magento.

- Old WP site permalink structure is `https://website.com/store/products/product-url`
- Magento  url structure is `https://www.website.com/category-name/product-url`

How can we achieve this using `htaccess`, so that matching links are redirected correctly?

TIA

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `category-name` varies, then I don't see any way you can do this solely from 301 rewrites in a .htaccess file. You may need to redirect the old URLs to a custom-coded script that will then redirect to the appropriate new URL, based on some sort of logic that will connect the old product URL to the appropriate new `category-name/product-url`

Answer (score 1):

As @Aric Watson states: you cannot do this with plain `.htaccess`, because the `category-name`-slug will not be predictable from `.htaccess`.

But... assuming you're only interested in creating 301's to the new URL's you don't actually need to know the new URL. A 301 to `/catalog/product/view/id/[product id]` would do as well, given that the canonical of your product detail page is set correct. So you won't lose any SEO value there.

In that scenario, you could write a script that writes those redirects according to a CSV that maps your old URL to the new product ID.

This function could look something like this:

```
/**
 * Import rule for Magento Community
 * @param $fromUrl
 * @param $toUrl
 */
public function createRuleCommunity($fromUrl, $toUrl)
{
    // Create rewrite:
    /** @var Mage_Core_Model_Url_Rewrite $rewrite */
    $rewrite = Mage::getModel('core/url_rewrite');

    // Check for existing rewrites:
    foreach($this->storeIds as $storeId)
    {
        // Attempt loading it first, to prevent duplicates:
        $rewrite->loadByIdPath($fromUrl);

        $rewrite->setStoreId($storeId);
        $rewrite->setOptions('RP');
        $rewrite->setIdPath($fromUrl);
        $rewrite->setRequestPath($fromUrl);
        $rewrite->setIsSystem(0);
        $rewrite->setTargetPath($toUrl);

        $rewrite->save();
    }
}
```

In this method, you could set `$toUrl` to `/catalog/product/view/id/[product id]`. But you could also set the new URL-key of the product, if you got that already. If you have the product ID, a simple `$urlKey = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id)->getUrlKey()` would do.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I'll surely give it a try on next project. The one I mentioned on this question, we happened to skip all the previous product specific SEO value & ended up only dealing with key categories. Cheers